# Floating infinitely an element with JS

Tags: javascript

Quick trouble, I wanna move infinitely from right to left an element (at this moment trying with a mouseover event).

```
function cucu2 () {
  document.getElementById('grande').style.cssFloat = 'right';
  document.getElementById('grande').addEventListener('mouseover', cucu, true);
}
function cucu () {
  document.getElementById('grande').style.cssFloat = 'left';
  document.getElementById('grande').addEventListener('mouseover', cucu2);
}
window.addEventListener('load', cucu);
```

It works perfectly on the right side, as soon as I mouseover near it moves the element to the left, however, on that side it just works ok the first time, the 2nd one seems to be delayed and ***actually takes 2-3 seconds with mouse over it to take effect*** and move the element to the left again. I'm guessing its something about the useCapture value of the listener, though if I set both listeners on either true or false the element moves just one time left, one time right and game over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is on each mouse over you attach the listeners again don't remove them, by the second time you mouseover both `cucu2` and `cucu` get called keeping `#grande` at `float: right`.

A quick way to fix it is remove the calling listeners after running it:

```js
function cucu2 () {
  document.getElementById('grande').style.cssFloat = 'right';
  document.getElementById('grande').addEventListener('mouseover', cucu, true);
  document.getElementById('grande').removeEventListener('mouseover', cucu2);
}
function cucu () {
  document.getElementById('grande').style.cssFloat = 'left';
  document.getElementById('grande').addEventListener('mouseover', cucu2);
  document.getElementById('grande').removeEventListener('mouseover', cucu);
}
window.addEventListener('load', cucu);
```

```css
#grande {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grande"></div>
```

A better way is to attach an event that will switch between `float: left` `float: right`:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var element = document.getElementById('grande');
  element.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    //if element is floated left we float it right
    element.style.cssFloat = element.style.cssFloat == 'right' ? 'left' : 'right';
  });
});
```

```css
#grande {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grande"></div>
```